# Firebase real time database set value query restarts activity every time I call this query

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, mobile

Here is my method in which I'm using firebase query to set/update new value in database

```
private fun saveInfo() {
    val newClicks = oldClicks?.toInt()?.plus(clicks).toString()
    if (userID != null) {
        databaseRef.child("PlanData/${userID.toString()}/clicks").setValue(newClicks)
    }
}
```

Whenever I call this method activity restarts again and adds that same activity in backstack

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: No application dose not crash , It just starts same activity again and add previous activity in backstack

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation, to see if something's wrong?

Comment: No, I did not try but it is updating values in database but in activity it is creating activity again

Comment: There isn't enough information to see the reason why the activity is recreated.